# .Net Core 2.0 debug logging is broken (still)

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core

However I configure my *appsettings.json* and *appsettings.Development.json*, I cannot get anything logged below Information messages unless I manually add *ConfigureLogging* to the WebHostBuilder setup, as follows:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug))
                .Build();
```

So now I'd like to set the log level dynamically based on the environment, but cannot figure out how to get access to an IHostingEnvironment instance in my Program Main() *before* setting up the WebHostBuilder with a reference to my *Startup* class.

I saw a post here with code similar to the following, however it's giving me a syntax error on the `GetService<Application>()` line, saying that *static types cannot be used as type arguments*:

```
var loggingLevel = LogLevel.Information;

IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var app = serviceProvider.GetService<Application>();
var hostingEnvironment = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    loggingLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is my *appsettings.json*:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Log4Net": {
    "ConfigFileRelativePath": "log4net.xml",
    "Repository": "NETCoreRepository"
  }
}
```

and *appsettings.Development.json*:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "Swagger": {
    "FileName": "MyController.xml"
  }
}
```

And my project's Debug panel does have the environment variable set:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  Development
```

Comment: Can you post your appSettings here? That typically defines the minimum logging level.

Comment: ok, added them.  I've tried many combinations, e.g. with "Debug" in both, with various providers (Console, etc), and nothing worked until I added the call to ConfigureLogging in the WebHostBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

For now, I've gone with the environment variable:

```
var loggingLevel = LogLevel.Information;
var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
if (env != null && env.ToLower().Equals("development"))
    loggingLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
```

Comment: If you would like to check whether your application is running in a particular environment, you may prefer to use env.IsEnvironment("environmentname") .It will correctly ignore casing for you actually

Comment: Right.  The point of my question, is that I am unable to get access to the "env" ("hostingEnvironment" in my example) prior to instantiating the WebHostBuilder.